# Ubuntu 12 : dpkg-reconfigure problems

Tags: ubuntu, console, keyboard

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server, freshly installed, however it is set to the wrong timezone. I tried to use dpkg-reconfigure tzdata to correct it, but I can't tell what I am selecting. When I move the cursor keys up and down I get @ characters next to the options (that don't disappear). All of my searching so far has found nothing, other than using dpkg-reconfigure console-setup, which has the same issue.

I am using putty to ssh to the system, there is no GUI installed. I want to know how to fix the keyboard issue so I can use it for other things. Trial and error eventually allowed me to select the correct timezone eventually, so that specific function is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Windows man, but it looks like problems with terminal emulation negotiation.

Have a look at the putty terminal emulation, and check the $TERM variable inside the shell. A good terminal is vt220. (You could try to `export TERM=vt220` and run dpkg-reconfigure again).

You could change timezone by hand. Have a look into this [Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16190/how-to-make-an-ubuntu-time-zone-change-stick)

Comment: This worked. the $TERM variable was set to xterm and putty was set to ESC[n~ ... I tried a few combinations of available settings and eventually VT400 on both worked best. Thanks!